# Regex for Markdown Table Syntax?

Tags: regex, github, markdown

I'm currently developing a tool that allows me to parse Github wikis; I'm trying to add support for Markdown tables, which are not supported by the parser I'm using.

I'm a bit stuck with the complicated table syntax. The official specification is [here](https://github.github.com/gfm/#tables-extension-):

```markdown
| Left align | Right align | Center align |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|
| This       |        This |     This     |
| column     |      column |    column    |
| will       |        will |     will     |
| be         |          be |      be      |
| left       |       right |    center    |
| aligned    |     aligned |   aligned    |
```

As you can see there's some structure but some parts are entirely optional.

I would like a regex that would capture the header (first line), the column alignment data (second line) and actual content as separate groups. It should contain at least one content line in order to match. The header and alignment data also has to obey certain rules as seen on the examples.

It's possible my approach is misguided (perhaps regex can be avoided?). If so, any answers leading to the same results easier are appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I need a regex solution to the same problem. Here's what I've got so far, will update it as I am able to improve it:

```
|(?:([^\r\n|]*)\|)+\r?\n\|(?:(:?-+:?)\|)+\r?\n(\|(?:([^\r\n|]*)\|)+\r?\n)+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/C2llo0S8xyZ22Nr7)

Tested with `javascript`

Comment: That's one scary regex. :)

Comment: I'm just going to drop this: `((\|[^|\r\n]*)+\|(\r?\n|\r)?)+` here, as another answer to such an old question is not worth it. Or, if you care about capture groups: `(?:(?:\|[^|\r\n]*)+\|(?:\r?\n|\r)?)+`

Comment: Why this is not the approved answer? This is what worked for me with `javascript`. But I just removed some unnecessary escape character which was cause for eslint errors and works great.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, and never finding a suitable answer, I eventually came up with the following.

```
^(\|[^\n]+\|\r?\n)((?:\|:?[-]+:?)+\|)(\n(?:\|[^\n]+\|\r?\n?)*)?$
```

Flags are "Global", and "Multiline".

Although it's not really based on [Sean's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29616512/6078214), it did end up being rather similar, with a few notable differences such as being a little shorter, completing in fewer steps (59 vs 126 steps, according to regex101.com), and having probably more "sensible" capturing groups. Plus it allows for "incomplete" tables too. (As in no "body"). (The reason I'm adding it in a separate answer is that I really do find it more useful, plus my ego would not allow me to do otherwise) ;).

In a nutshell:

- It will only allow for "strict" markdown tables, where every line starts and ends with a `|` character, and the "cell alignments" line is properly formatted.
- First group captures the "head", the second group the "cell alignments" line, and the (optional) third group captures the "body".
- It needs at least one completed and correctly formatted "alignment" cell to consider it a table, but will match incomplete tables otherwise (i.e. with no "body").

Tested in Java, (Android) and here:

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/M5wAoq/1/)

and here:

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/kE3oEe2To0ehCTz0)

Hope it helps someone. :)

Answer (score 4):

Somethin that I did:

1. Regex for parsing table header and delimiter!!

```
[|]?(\s+[A-Za-z0-9 -_*#@$%:;?!.,\/\\]+\s+)[|]?[|]?(\s+[A-Za-z0-9 -_*#@$%:;?!.,\/\\]+\s+)[|]?[|]?(\s+[A-Za-z0-9 -_*#@$%:;?!.,\/\\]+\s+)[|]?\r?\n?\|?:-+:\|?:-+:\|?:-+:\|?
```

—modifier - global

2. Regex for delimiter between header and text

```
\|?:-+:\|?:-+:\|?:-+:\|?\r?\n?
```

-- modifier - global

3. Regex for parsing ALL elements before and after header delimiter!

```
[|]?(\s+[A-Za-z0-9 -_*#@$%:;?!.,\/\\]+\s+)[|]?[|]?(\s+[A-Za-z0-9 -_*#@$%:;?!.,\/\\]+\s+)[|]?[|]?(\s+[A-Za-z0-9 -_*#@$%:;?!.,\/\\]+\s+)[|]?\r?\n?
```

—modifiers - global, multiline

This is table, for parsing.

```
| Tables        | Are           | Cool  |
|:-------------:|:-------------:|:-----:|
| col 3 is      |    r-l        | $1600 |
| col 2 is      | centered      |   $12 |
| zebra stripes | are neat      |    $1 |
```

Comment: Thanks for the regex: I've used it in a markdown parser, [slimdown-js](https://github.com/erikvullings/slimdown-js), which converts the table to HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a really naive solution to **Find** tables in md and then do some manipulations on them (separately on each table).

the solution is to get all the rows that start with a vertical line after a line break (|). This is in Js:

```
 const findTables = (md) => {
   const tables = md.match(/(\n\|([^\n])*\|)*/g);
   return tables?.map((t) => t.replace("\n", "")).filter((t) => t);
 }
```

If the tables is not in correct syntax inside (rows columns etc.) it will get it anyway...

So, really naive but gets all the tables inside a Markdown file as an array.